# `gtsummary` and `papaja` integration for `kable` tables

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, gtsummary, papaja

I am trying to use a `gtsummary` table within a `papaja::apa6_pdf` document to include a formatted (with caption) `kable` table. However, it's not rendering as expected. In contrast, the `gtsummary` `kable` table renders well in a normal `rmarkdown::pdf_document` (though `gtsummary` `kableExtra` table also doesn't look great). I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to get `gtsummary` and `papaja` to play well together to produce a "pretty" PDF table. Thank you!

### rmarkdown::pdf_document

````
```
---
title: "gtsummary + rmarkdown::pdf_document"
output: pdf_document
---
```
```{r}
library(gtsummary)

trial %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
  modify_caption("This is a table about trials") %>% 
  as_kable()

trial %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
  modify_caption("This is another table about trials") %>% 
  as_kable_extra()
```
````

[image: gtsummary-pdf_output]

### papaja::apa6_pdf

````
```
---
title             : "gtsummary + papaja"
shorttitle        : "gtsummary + papaja"

author: 
  - name          : "First Author"
    affiliation   : "1"
    corresponding : yes    # Define only one corresponding author
    address       : "Postal address"
    email         : "my@email.com"

affiliation:
  - id            : "1"
    institution   : "Wilhelm-Wundt-University"


authornote: >

abstract: "my abstract"
  
keywords          : "keywords"
wordcount         : "X"

bibliography      : []

floatsintext      : no
figurelist        : no
tablelist         : no
footnotelist      : no
linenumbers       : yes
mask              : no
draft             : no

documentclass     : "apa6"
classoption       : "man"
output            : papaja::apa6_pdf
---

```{r}
library(papaja)
library(gtsummary)

trial %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
  modify_caption("This is a table about trials") %>% 
  as_kable()

trial %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
  modify_caption("This is another table about trials") %>% 
  as_kable_extra()
```
````

[image: gtsummary-papaja]

Comment: I am not sure why the kable output is not recognizing the markdown `**` to bold the header in the papaja output. But you can replace the header to not include the bolding with `modify_header(list(all_stat_cols() ~ "{level}, N = {n}", label ~ "Characteristic"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the most general solution is to specify the table output format in `as_kable()`.

```
trial %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
  modify_caption("This is a table about trials") %>%
  as_kable(format = 'pipe')
```

The PDF then looks like the following:
[image]

This also seems to work with bold labels:

```
trial %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
  modify_caption("This is a table about trials") %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  as_kable(format = 'pipe')
```

The PDF then looks like the following:
[image]

P.S.: It is also possible to specify the table output format globally. In a **papaja** document, you could add the following line to your *setup* chunk.

```
options(knitr.table.format = 'pipe')
```

If added, you can then completely omit the call to `as_kable()` (but a warning message will be printed).

Comment: Thank you! This is better but still not giving me what I need. For example, bold row labels are not properly interpreted in pandoc `
trial %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
  bold_labels() %>% 
    caption = "A table",
    format.args = list(na_string = ""),
    format = "pandoc"
  )  as_tibble() %>%
  apa_table(...)
`

Comment: Hi @maia-sh, I just updated my answer with a more general solution.

Comment: `as_kable(format = 'pipe')` was the magic solution it seems! Thank you